# Sticky position to two column grid with a parent div not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I want one column of a two column grid to stay sticky. I am trying to create a vertical navbar specific to a particuar div in a single page site with a fixed horizontal navbar to the whole page.However the sticky is not happening.

I have created a div- strategy-container;nested in it two divs using grid.
I want the div with class sidebar to be sticky.

I understand that this will be sticky to its parent div i.e. the strategy-container div.

But the sidenav is also moving.

The strategy-container has relative positioning with overflow visible.

Why is this so?

```css
.strategy-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.sidenav {
  /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  /* Set the width of the sidebar */
  position: sticky;
  /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: 50px;
  /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="container-fluid strategy-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidenav">

      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">

      some stuff to be scrolled;
      <br><br><br> Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae
      nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id
      agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum,
      altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum
      definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text
      to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
      his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
      laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.<br><br> some stuff to be scrolled;
      <br><br><br> Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae
      nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id
      agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum,
      altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum
      definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text
      to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
      his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
      laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.<br><br> some stuff to be scrolled;
      <br><br><br> Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae
      nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id
      agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum,
      altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum
      definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text
      to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
      his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
      laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.<br><br> some stuff to be scrolled;
      <br><br><br> Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae
      nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id
      agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum,
      altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum
      definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text
      to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
      his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
      laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.<br><br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it because the column sticks to the row div as its parent.
How can i Implement what I need?

Thankyou :).

Answer (score 0):

The sticky position is working on the `.sidenav` but it's already at the top it doesn't appear to be sticking.

Instead use `sticky-top` (Bootstrap 4 class) on an *inner* div of the sidebar...

```
<div class="container-fluid strategy-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidenav">
            <div class="sticky-top">
             <a href="#">About</a>
             <a href="#">Services</a>
             <a href="#">Clients</a>
             <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/kJxzd16GL5

Comment: Hi, I tried using sticky top.The same code works good on codpen but doesnt seem to stick when coupled with other divs. The page has a horizontal fixed navbar with scroll spy for the whole page. Is this anyhow preventing sticky-top. The body is positioned relative. Could there be any mistake here?:). Thank you